# В android 13 приложение не видит разрешений

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Начиная с 13 android api 33 приложение не видит разрешений  до 13 все ок
В че может быть причина?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Просто добавим, что если вы попытаетесь проверить или запросить WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE на Android 13+, он всегда будет возвращать false. Таким образом, вам придется полностью пропустить проверку/запрос разрешения на Android 13+

Answer (score 0):

Возможно для Андроид 13 надо использовать разрешение android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES